# How do I search for a value in a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write some python code to see if a value in a dictionary has already been passed into a list of dictionaries or not. I start with some dictionary, say

```
dict = {"info": "some_info", "value": 1, "type": "some_type"}
```

and a list of dictionaries containing some sets of this information, say

```
list_of_dicts = [{"info": "some_info", "value": 1, "name": "some_name"},
{"info": "some_more_info", "value": 2, "name": "some_other_name"},
{"info": "some_other_info", "value": 3, "name": "another_name"}]
```

The value type in dict is not a typo - the info I am storing is slightly different in dict to list_of_dicts. I want to look at the values in dict and see if they are already in list_of_dicts. In reality, I will be looping through many dicts so I will need something like:

```
for dict in dicts:
    if dict["info"] in *list_of_dicts* and dict["value"] in *list_of_dicts*:
        print("Already in list_of_dicts, skipping")
    else:
        print("Storing in list of dicts")
```

Where I have written *list_of_dicts* is where I'm struggling to write the correct logic. I want to check each entry in list_of_dicts to see whether the info in dict is already stored. I need the "info" value and the "value" value to both already be in the same entry of list_of_dicts for a particular dict for this dict to be skipped. How can I write this?

Comment: What is your expected output?? Please add it

Comment: This sounds really inefficient. Could you maybe give some insights on what you are trying to achieve with the code? 
To be minimally invasive with your code, I would probably suggest using a dict of dicts instead of a list of dicts.
E.g. `{(info, value): dict1, (info2, value2): dict2, ...}`. Then it is really easy and efficient to find your dict.

Comment: Iterate through the list of dicts and check the values in each dict one by one.

Comment: Another alternative is to maintain a set of tuples with `info, value` pairs that you check for existence, if, depending on whether you're on a version of Python were dict are ordered or not, the order of a list is important.

Comment: Your question is not clear as you are both defining a dictionary with the name `dict` (already over-shadowing the built-in name) and then you shadow this name with `for dict in dicts`. Can you clarify what you want to do? Do you want to check if `info` and `value` from the dict in the start of your question already exist in the list? If so, you are already doing that but confused yourself because of bad naming. If you have `d = {"info": "some_info", "value": 1, "type": "some_type"}` then all you need is `for test in dicts: if d["info"] == test["info"] and d["value"] == test["value"]: # match`

Answer (score 0):

How I would do that is to maintain another datastructure that keeps track of the things in `list_of_dicts`.

This can be temporary if this information is only needed once or if you need to add to `list_of_dicts` multiple times you can keep it around.

```
# This constructs a set from the values that are already in the list:
already_seen = {(d['info'], d['value') for d in list_of_dicts}

for dct in dicts:
    seen_key = (dct['info'], dct['value'])
    if seen_key in already_seen:
        print("Already in list_of_dicts, skipping")
    else:
        print("Storing in list of dicts")
        # And when you've added it, don't forget to do:
        already_seen.add(seen_key)
```

Testing a set for membership takes constant time instead of linear time like any solution you could have if you only had `list_of_dicts`, so it is also a lot faster, especially with a lot of dicts in `list_of_dicts`!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, here are the solutions

```
dictAlfa = {"info": "some_info", "value": 1, "type": "some_type"}


listBeta = [{"info": "some_info", "value": 1, "name": "some_name"},
{"info": "some_more_info", "value": 2, "name": "some_other_name"},
{"info": "some_other_info", "value": 3, "name": "another_name"}]


for Beta in listBeta:
    if dictAlfa["info"] == Beta["info"] and dictAlfa["value"] == Beta["value"]:
        print("Already in list_of_dicts, skipping")
    else: 
        print("Storing in list of dicts")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to append a dictionary in list_of_dicts based on **unique_together** key **info** and **value**. You can try this code:

```
d = {"info": "some_infoa", "value": 1, "name": "some_name"}
list_of_dicts = [{"info": "some_info", "value": 1, "name": "some_name"} , {"info": "some_more_info", "value": 2, "name": "some_other_name"}, {"info": "some_other_info", "value": 3, "name": "another_name"}]

res = all(((not (d.get('info') == mydict.get('info') and d.get('value') == mydict.get('value'))) for mydict in list_of_dicts))
if res:
    list_of_dicts.append(d)

print(list_of_dicts)
```

Here i have checked same info and value dict exists or not. If exists I am returning **False** in iterator of **all()** so the **res** will be **False**. Note that If all elements of iterator are true then **all()** returns True.